# Singular or plural following a list of singular items

Tags: grammatical-number

Here's the sentence:

> I know what if, him, his, and will means/mean.

Comment: Use "means". You're talking about yourself only, so it should remain singular.

Comment: Thx. it just sounds strange.  I thought since I was referring to a list, it should be mean.  Guess not.